# Bootstrap form aligned, vertical, and horizontal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

I am trying to make a pretty form that will work boostrap-responsive.css for mobile use. Before I used tables, and it worked fine without bootstrap-responsive, but now it becomes very ugly when scaled down.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**:

1. Get headline/label for each input to be in top(horizontal).
2. Aligned right side(so it will look pretty on a phone).
3. Have glyphicons prepended - this is what it makes difficult, since with them I can't format it correctly

If I am too unclear of what I want to accomplish, you can also take a look at my super hightech picture that describes the form:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEj8I.jpg

My code half working code is:

```
<form class="form-vertical" ....>
<fieldset>
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span8 input-prepend">
        <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <span class="add-on"><i id="titleicon" class="icon-minus-sign"></i></span>
        <input  type="text" name="title" id="title"   />
      </div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="span2 input-prepend">
        <label class="control-label" for="price">Price</label>
        <span class="add-on"><i id="priceicon" class="icon-minus-sign"></i></span>
        <input type="text" id="price" name="price"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
      <label class="control-label" for="description">Description</label>
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i id="descriptionicon" class="icon-minus-sign"></i>/span>
        <textarea  name="description" rows="6" class="field span6" id="descriptionfield"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>¨
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I am not sure I formatted it correctly for stackoverflow(this is my first question) so it is here too with syntax highlighting: http://pastebin.com/LzN1vbYi

I know there are tons of answers to very similar question, but that prepended glyph makes none of the code work. I tried around 15 different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this form

```
<div class="row-fluid>
 <div class="span12>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <span class="add-on"><i id="titleicon" class="icon-minus-sign"></i></span>
        <input  type="text" name="title" id="title"   />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="price">Price</label>
    <div class="controls">
     <span class="add-on"><i id="priceicon" class="icon-minus-sign"></i></span>
        <input type="text" id="price" name="price"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>`
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will make the input all horizontal, and not vertical like I the picture I posted. Beside that, the glyphicons aren't prepended.